# Submit data and image into mysql by http-post

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post

Submit imageView with other fields to mysql where  real image stores in folder in localhost and path of the image in mysql table, but image and other fields are not store as expected.

i have tried code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302340/android-application-to-send-image-to-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top)

Java Code:

```
    public class AddProduct extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String[] types;
    String[] subcategories;
    Spinner spinnerCategory,spinnerSubcategory;

    EditText editproductname,editproductdescrip,editproductprice,editmoreinfo,editcategory;
    TextView txtStatus; 
    String image_str;

    ImageView imageview;
    public Button Addproduct,btnselectpic, uploadButton;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    public static String PRODUCT_URL = "http:localhost/folder1/addproducts.php";
    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private String upLoadServerUri;
    private String imagepath = null;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addpro);

        txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
        spinnerCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercategory);
        spinnerSubcategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnersubcategory);
        editproductname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.proname);
        editproductdescrip=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prodesc);
        editproductprice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prodprice);
        editmoreinfo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prodinfo);
        btnselectpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
          uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        Addproduct=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnproduct);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewUpload);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Addproduct.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://localhost/folder1/addproducts.php";
          ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

      //set Array for parent spinner "Category"
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

            //set Array for child spinner Subcategory1
           final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category1sub, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerSubcategory.setAdapter(adapter1);

            //set Array for child spinner Subcategory2
           final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category2sub, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerSubcategory.setAdapter(adapter2);

            //set Array for child spinner Subcategory3
            final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category3sub,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerSubcategory.setAdapter(adapter3);

            spinnerCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){
                    String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    if(selectedItem.trim().equals("Electronics")){
                        spinnerSubcategory.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    }
                    else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("Fashion")){
                        spinnerSubcategory.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    }
                    else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("HomeAppliance")){
                        spinnerSubcategory.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    }
                    types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected : " +types[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                }   
            });             
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0 == btnselectpic) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        } else if (arg0 == uploadButton) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AddProduct.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
            txtStatus.setText("uploading started.....");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    uploadFile(imagepath);
                }
            }).start();
        } else if (arg0 == Addproduct) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AddProduct.this, "","Uploading file...", true);
            txtStatus.setText("uploading started.....");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     new CreateProduct().execute();
                      //uploadFile(imagepath);
                } 
            }).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        txtStatus.setText("Uploading file path:" + imagepath);
    }
}

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
           int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;    
    }   

    class CreateProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(AddProduct.this);
            //dialog.setMessage("Creating Product...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
            }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... paramss) {
            int success;
            String strtype = spinnerCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String strsubtype = spinnerSubcategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String productname=editproductname.getText().toString(); 
           String productdescription=editproductdescrip.getText().toString();
            String productprice=editproductprice.getText().toString();
            String moreinfo=editmoreinfo.getText().toString();

        try {
            //Building parameter
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtcategory",strtype));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtsubcategory",strsubtype));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtproductname", productname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtproductdescription", productdescription));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtproductprice", productprice));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtmoreinfo",moreinfo));     

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(PRODUCT_URL, "POST",params);
            //full json response
            Log.d("Adding Product", json.toString());
            //json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if(success == 1){
            Log.d("Product Added!", json.toString());
            Intent c= new Intent(AddProduct.this, ProductList.class);
            startActivity(c);
            finish();
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Product not added",json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once deleted
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    ///Upload image separately,

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String tmp_name = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" + imagepath);
                }
            });
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("image", tmp_name);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\""+tmp_name+ "\"" +lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // send multipart form data necessary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is: "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here: \n\n"+" C:/localhost/iagent/images";
                            //messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this,"File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }   }); }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        txtStatus.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this,"MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this,"Got Exception : see logcat ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception","Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        } // End else block
    }   
}`
```

**using PHP code -**

```
<?php

$category = $_POST["txtcategory"]; 
$subcategory = $_POST["txtsubcategory"]; 
$productname = $_POST["txtproductname"];
$productdescrip = $_POST["txtproductdescription"];
$productprice = $_POST["txtproductprice"];
$moreinfo = $_POST["txtmoreinfo"];  
$file   =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
//file_put_contents('newImage.JPEG',$decoded);


if($productname == null || $productprice == null){
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Field is vacant";
die(json_encode($response));
}

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","passowrd","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Database Error!";
die(json_encode($response));
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
///
try{
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
    }else{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="http://192.168.1.5/iagent/images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
            //$caption=$_POST['caption'];

    $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (pro_img_path) VALUES ('$location')");
            //header("location: addimage.php");
    }                   

//$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO products(category, subcategory,product_name,product_price) VALUES ('$category','$subcategory','$productname','$productprice')");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO products(category,subcategory,product_name,product_descrip,product_price,more_info) VALUES ('$category','$subcategory','$productname','$productdescrip','$productprice','$moreinfo')");

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Product Added Successful!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
catch(Exception $e){
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Product Not Added";
die(json_encode($response));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Logcat error as follows**

```
09-03 03:33:11.637: D/dalvikvm(1316): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 5% free 2948K/3088K, paused 78ms, total 82ms
09-03 03:33:11.637: I/dalvikvm-heap(1316): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
09-03 03:33:11.697: D/dalvikvm(1316): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3566K/3712K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
09-03 03:33:12.247: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:12.367: D/gralloc_goldfish(1316): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-03 03:33:12.737: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:15.417: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 102 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:15.867: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:18.307: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 176 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:20.487: D/dalvikvm(1316): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 5% free 3904K/4068K, paused 269ms, total 275ms
09-03 03:33:23.167: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:24.457: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:24.847: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:26.757: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:30.887: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1316): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-03 03:33:46.937: D/dalvikvm(1316): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 5% free 4271K/4476K, paused 273ms, total 292ms
09-03 03:33:47.337: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:48.987: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 136 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:53.847: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 151 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:54.607: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:55.037: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:55.247: D/dalvikvm(1316): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 470K, 12% free 4314K/4860K, paused 71ms, total 80ms
09-03 03:33:55.247: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:55.857: I/uploadFile(1316): HTTP Response is: OK: 200
09-03 03:33:56.127: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:56.477: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:33:57.007: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:34:22.467: W/dalvikvm(1316): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a74ba8)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-101
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316): Process: crawes.product.iagent, PID: 1316
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:109)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at crawes.product.iagent.AddProduct$CreateProduct.onPreExecute(AddProduct.java:193)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at crawes.product.iagent.AddProduct$3.run(AddProduct.java:154)
09-03 03:34:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-03 03:34:23.207: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 183 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:34:24.047: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 191 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:34:24.707: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 126 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:34:25.697: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 253 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:34:26.427: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 190 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:34:26.657: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity crawes.product.iagent.AddProduct has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b3e8c290 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at crawes.product.iagent.AddProduct.onClick(AddProduct.java:150)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-03 03:34:28.137: E/WindowManager(1316):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 03:34:28.137: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 03:39:22.877: I/Process(1316): Sending signal. PID: 1316 SIG: 9
```

Comment: use AsyncTask **OR** Thread **not both** at the same time ... especially do not call exectute of AsyncTask inside non UI thread (what is written in the AsyncTask's documentation but you don't even try to read it)

Comment: Hey selvin thanks for your awesome comments, which did not help me in anyway.moreover the tip was very vague.

Comment: i love wannabe programmers... please show me the line where you are calling exectute method of AsyncTask