# loopj - Android Asynchronous Http Client upload image from drawable

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, loopj

I'm trying to send an image from drawable to rest web service use android asynchronous http client. This link show how to send image use path,

[Uploading an image from Android (with Android Asynchronous Http Client) to rails server (with paperclip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245469/uploading-an-image-from-android-with-android-asynchronous-http-client-to-rails?lq=1)

Is it possible to send image from drawable? I have already look from [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) about how to send byte image, but in my code it's keep return error that the picture is missing. Here is my code

```
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

            username = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
            name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString();

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_user);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();

            if(isOnline()){
                params.put("email", username);
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("phone", phone);
                params.put("picture", new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte), "user.jpg");
                invokeWS(params);
                return true;
            }
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's  possible to send image from drawable, but you should convert your image to base64 string  like this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);          
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and then send the string to the server :

```
params.put("image", image_str);
```

For more details look here [Android application to send image to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302340/android-application-to-send-image-to-mysql?rq=1)